# Failed to build Android native tutorial project in macOS Catalina

Tags: android, android-ndk

I created a native Android c++ project from the Android tutorials. I get the following compile errors: (in macOS Catalina)

```
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /Volumes/DATA/android-sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/ninja with arguments {-C /Users/dd/tmp/ndk-test/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a native-lib}
  ninja: Entering directory `/Users/dd/tmp/ndk-test/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a'
  [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o
  FAILED: CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o 
  /Volumes/DATA/android-sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi26 --gcc-toolchain=/Volumes/DATA/android-sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Volumes/DATA/android-sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot  -Dnative_lib_EXPORTS  -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o -c /Users/dd/tmp/ndk-test/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
  In file included from /Users/dd/tmp/ndk-test/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:1:
  In file included from /Volumes/DATA/android-sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/jni.h:28:
  In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdint.h:52:
  In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:32:
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
  #error Unsupported architecture
   ^
  In file included from /Users/dd/tmp/ndk-test/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:1:
  In file included from /Volumes/DATA/android-sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/jni.h:28:
  In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdint.h:52:
  In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
  #error architecture not supported
   ^
  In file included from /Users/dd/tmp/ndk-test/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:1:
  In file included from /Volumes/DATA/android-sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/jni.h:28:
  In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdint.h:52:
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
  typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
          ^
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
          ^
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
          ^
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean 'uint32_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
          ^
  ......
          ^
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
          ^
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean 'uint32_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
          ^
  ......
          ^
  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  20 errors generated.
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

My other NDK projects fail to build as well.

Comment: Does your environment contain any variable pointing towards your Xcode.app directory? Also, does `/Volumes/DATA/android-sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/stdint.h` exist?

Comment: Can you file a bug with your repro case at https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/new/choose? That shouldn't be happening and it doesn't match what we've seen in testing.

Comment: Other info that would be really helpful would be the output after adding `-v` to your cflags. That'll make clang print out the full arguments that it's using as well as the include search order.

Comment: https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1104

Answer (score 2):

remove `CPATH` environment variable solves this issue

https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1104#issuecomment-555981351

Comment: Thank you! But I need this flag to compile Boost on macOS. Any idea?

Comment: If i do not use CPATH it throws limits.h file not found error

Comment: I don't have any CPATH but still facing this issue